# Polymer RTL layout

Tags: css, polymer, material-design, right-to-left, polymer-1.0

I wanted to know if I can implement RTL layouts in Polymer, and if yes how can I do that?

I tried to search the web but I did not find answers. also I am new to polymer so am unable to figure out if this is possible or not!

Comment: Thanks but am looking for something specific to polymer-project.

Comment: Uhmm. Why not use something that has been built into CSS for decades? Anything that polymer uses will actually be implementing that behind the scenes. Why not use the simplest solution?

Comment: can you be more specific about RTL? is it just the text you're talking about?

Comment: No the text is easy, it is more about the components like tabs for example